# How to create a dataframe for this R code (Absolute Beginner question)

Tags: r

How do I use multiple .txt files as a dataframe for this R code?
txt files contain data about collocation use over time. The following code should do all the work, but I don't even know how to import the dataframe.
Can someone tell me where do I put the filepath, etc.?

```
#Calculate Gwet's AC1; b...input data frame
i = 1 
v <- c() 
while(i+1 < ncol(b)) {
   n=(gwet.ac1.raw(b[,i:(i+2)])[3])
   v<- c(v, n) 
   i= i+1 
} 
#Prepare data frame
h<-seq(from, to, by = 1); 
g<-data.frame(h,v) #Produce graph
p<-ggplot(g, aes(x = g[,1], y =g[,2])) + 
    xlim(from, to)+ scale_x_continuous(breaks = 
seq(from, to, by = 10)) + 
    geom_point() + xlab("Time") + ylab("AC1")
p + stat_smooth(method = "gam", formula = y ~ s(x, bs = "cr", fx=FALSE, k =10), size = 1, 
fill="#707070", level = 0.95 ) + 
    stat_smooth(method = "gam", formula = y ~ s(x, bs = "cr", 
          fx=FALSE, k =10), size = 1, fill="#FFFF00", level = 0.99)
```

Comment: `gwet.ac1.raw()` looks like a function from a package, possibly `irrCAC`. It is run here on the presumption that a matrix of ratings has been loaded into an object called `b`. The code you are looking for is upstream of this code and I don't think we will have any particular knowledge to help with that. If you're lucky, it's as simple as `b <- read.tsv(YOUR_TXT_FILE)` but we don't know anything about your files or what the code here is expecting.

Comment: Now I get the following errors Error in gwet.ac1.raw(b[, i:(i + 2)]) : 
  could not find function "gwet.ac1.raw".     Error in seq(from, to, by = 1) : object 'from' not found.   Error in ggplot(g, aes(x = g[, 1], y = g[, 2])) : 
  could not find function "ggplot".   It seems that I need to import the packages, but idk how? I also don't know how to read multiple txt files (read.tsv doesn't do it).

Comment: This sounds like a workflow involving a few questions, most (almost certainly all) of which have been answered here on SO. Break it into steps: 1) read one file in. 2) install and load the packages you need, including possibly `irrCAC` and `ggplot2`. 3) Try and run the code using the one file. 4) Load a list of files and combine them